# HapiJS assert request in handler

Tags: hapi.js

I have multiple endpoints starting with `/networks/{networkId}/*`. I don't want to have logic to find a network and execute some extra validation on it, in every handler. Is there any way to solve this on a higher level? Ex. plugins/server method etc?

In every handler I have the following boilerplate code:

```
import networkRepo from 'common/repositories/network';

// handler.js
export default (req, reply) => {
  return networkRepo.findById(req.params.networkId).then(network => {
    // Logic to validate whether the logged user belongs to the network
    // Logic where I need the network instance
  });
}
```

The best situation would be:

```
// handler.js
export default (req, reply) => {
  console.log(req.network); // This should be the network instance
}
```

Comment: why are you calling reply.continue()?  Also your test doesn't look right at all

Comment: I've modified the question

Comment: I have written an answer

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve what you want is to either create a generic function that you can call first inside your handler or alternatively create an internal hapi route which will perform you look-up and return value to your other handler.  Internal routes can then be accesses by server.inject from within your other handler, see options called [allowInternals](http://hapijs.com/api#serverinjectoptions-callback) for more details,  I can write pseudo-code to help!

```
[{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/getNetworkByID/{id}',
    config: {
        isInternal: true,
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            return networkRepo.findById(req.params.networkId).then(network => {
            // Logic to validate whether the logged user belongs to the network
                // Logic where I need the network instance
                reply(network.network);
            });

        }
    }
},
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/networks/{id}',
    config: {
        isInternal: true,
        handler: function (request, reply) {

            request.server.inject({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/getNetworkByID/' + request.params.id,
                allowInternals: true
            }, (res) => {

                console.log(res.result.network) //network
            });

        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Could you add some simple pseudo code that passes an object from handler X to handler Y

Comment: Hope this explains better